# What is Oracle zone map in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle

Oracle has a special kind of materialized view called zone map.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dwhsg/using-zone-maps.html#GUID-7E5C3F5A-C1F5-4A5E-A501-DB50B8948263 .
Does Postgresql has similar kind of materialized view of Oracle zone map?
If Not, what is the closest object in Postgresql?

Comment: That sounds like a concept of column store. PostgreSQL doesn't have a column store.

Comment: "*A zone map stores information per zone instead of per row."* this sounds a little bit like a [BRIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/brin-intro.html) in Postgres.